# How should I target a web-based admin tool for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I would like to venture into Android development and hopefully iOS. What I have in mind is client apps that can run on mobile, for example data collection that also picks GPS Data on location and all then a web-based admin that shows pretty much everything. This is where we can have maps and charts for data analysis. My target is enterprise apps running on these platforms.

Someone mentioned [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/home/) as a potential framework to accomplish this.  Would this be a good choice in my case?

Just bumped into [rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be on the right lane or not really, it all depends on the objectives you set for your application or mobile web page.

You say:

> Web Based admin that shows pretty much everything and clients running on phones (Android n iOS)

The question is wether what you want to do with the phone based clients is doable with just a Web Page, do you need something like Phonegap, or do you want to go with full native development in both platforms.

Phonegap is a good solution if you want quick development, but full native is better, phonegap is a solution for developers not customers, the way in which the app will work in both cases is quite diferent.

If you provide some more details I could give you a better answer, but with the info you provide the best I can say is, you need to check your specific need and do some research before deciding what you are going to do.

There is incredible amounts of information about this on the web and on stackoverflow, im almost sure that you can find what you need there.

Start by checking out the related questions to this one. Somewhere around -------------->

Comment: Good points. Looks like I achieve pretty much using jquerymobile cept when I need to interact with the Phones hardware. Pretty much what it was on desktop machines till most apps went web.

Answer (score 3):

Something like Phonegap is only necessary if you need to hook into device APIs that aren't available to the browser - the camera, the address book, etc. If you can do the web-based admin as a normal mobile-friendly website, there's not necessarily any reason to wrap it in an app.

Comment: Exactly, recently I've been researching this as well and ceejayoz hit the nail on the head. My app needs the ability to take pictures so I will need to use PhoneGap or something similar. If you don't need access to these things then building a mobile site would be much easier.